# Can't get JSON from PHP url within AngularJS factory

Tags: angularjs

I want to call .get in Angular factory. Can I please have any help why mydata is staying empty. I can see in console that json is loading but mydata variable has no value:

.factory('People', function($http) {
$http.get("http://www.example.com/service_2.php").success(function(response) { var mydata = response;});

Comment: What does console.log(response) give you?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes it logs the record but if i send JSON statically then controller shows right values and with above returned response as 'null'.

Comment: Controller is:
 
.controller('MContactCtrl', function($scope, People) {
  $scope.values = alert(People.all());
})

and all function: return {
    all: function() {
      return mydata;

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet is good but maybe you should try making **mydata** a global variable. that is, declare it outside the inner function and set it to null. So, upon the complete execution of the $http.get, echo **mydata** on a new line.

Comment: It shows JSON when i check in console but my controller stays empty and no results though if i put same JSON inside array statically it works.